# Creating a new Class without creating a new window in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a game that uses Swing but the problem is, in the code, I have to create a few classes and call a method in them. Because those methods are in subclasses of the class that uses swing, when I create it, it creates a new window of the same swing component and starts doing everything there. Is there a way to accomplish what I want without having multiple swing windows?

Here is where I'm creating the subclasses and calling their method.

```
    new Chapter1(player).engage();

    new Chapter2(player).engage();
```

I've tried just doing

```
    Chapter1().engage(player);

    Chapter2().engage(player);
```

but that requires for the engage() method to be static which causes errors in my whole program. as a lot of methods need to be inherited and aren't static. Is there a way around this or will I have to deal with multiple windows?

Edit:

A little more information about what the windows do. I created a console in swing for myself and I print a lot of information to it. The engage methods just print more things but I want them to be in the same window rather than printing in their own windows

Comment: You said the class in question extends a class that extends a swing component. Do you need this? You can make a separate class without subclassing any swing component.

Comment: Your question is unanswerable, and your terminology is wrong. You're not implementing swing. You're using swing. A method can't be a subclass. You can't create a method, only call it. Post a minimal but complete exemple reproducing the problem, tell us what the expected result is a,d what the desired result is.

Comment: @Takendarkk Well I need to be able to print to the swing component. Would that still be possible if I didn't have a subclass of the swing?

Comment: @JBNizet My bad, I'll fix my terminology to clear some things up. I didn't preview my post first

Comment: You can have 1 class which is a swing component which just displays data. Then you have a second class which **is not** a swing component that handles what data gets sent to the 1st class. This is basically trying to separate the logic code from the display code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should practice and MVC design.  This means you should decouple your GUI from any data store or data manipulation that is displayed.  In other words you should create one Frame.  Frame could take different Chapters to display data.  It sounds like you have Chapters as a UI itself which is something you should avoid especially if you will be inheriting for them with out any UI changes.

See: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html

Comment: okay, I'll look into it and try that to see if it works, thanks!